# P trap from disposal is lower than wall pipe

Tags: plumbing

[image]Any ideas for making this work as of right now the water is building up in the sink. Drains but drains slowly.

Comment: Photo would help a lot. But yo me, this sounds much more like a clog than a problem with the p-trap installation.

Comment: p-trap is always filled with water. use a bucket and unscrew it (no tools required) and clean it up

Comment: Picture added thanks for the help

Comment: Is this a new sink/disposal? The outlet on the disposal should be higher than where the trap goes into the wall. Looks like the outlet is slightly lower. Not enough to make water sit in the sink but low enough where water will sit in the disposal. As others said if water is sitting in the sink there's probably a clog. If the disposal sits too low that should be corrected.

Comment: I changed the disposal, yes. I don't think it's a clog I augered it but who know's it could be. I feel like it has to do with gravity and the piping going into the wall but I'm far from an expert.